# In Python, what is the best way to update a Class dictionary dynamically in this example

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a server Push to client that looks like this in its module...

`module.py`

```
class Stream(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.object_message = {'movie1': '0', 'movie2': '0', 'movie3': '0'}

    def event_stream(self):
        sc = Stream()
        print sc.object_message['movie1']
        yield 'data: %s\n\n' % sc.object_message['movie1']
```

It is built on a Flask service that has a client side Server-Sent Events mechanism polling for data from `event_stream`. I have that part working so for now my UI get the test `0`data every few seconds.
Now I am trying to modify this data from a running process dynamically.

Here is a test I tried so far...

```
class RequestTags(object):

    def process(self, arg1):
        sc = Stream()
        sc.object_message['movie1'] = 1
        sc.object_message['movie2'] = 2
...
```

While `event_stream` is polling, I triggered `process` in an attempt to update the initialized variable in Stream. I also tried a static Stream variable. I have looked at Borg and Singleton patterns but just seem to be a little green on how this can be done in my current use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like directly accessing a class level variable works. **I will keep this up for a bit before accepting to give the Python experts a chance to offer a more Pythonic way of doing and why.** Basically this solved my challenge otherwise.

```
class RequestTags(object):

    tags = {'tag1': '0', 'tag2': '0', 'tag3': '0'}
.
.
.
# adding new data inline
self.tags['tag1'] = <change inline>
.
.
.

class Stream(object):

    def event_stream(self):
        yield 'data: %s\n\n' % RequestTags.tags['tag1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new instances of the Stream() class in both process and event_stream. To get the behaviour you're looking for, I'd recommend passing sc as a parameter to stream.

Something like this:

```
class RequestTags(object):

    def process(self, arg1, sc):
        sc.object_message['movie1'] = 1
        sc.object_message['movie2'] = 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this and a few similar modifications don't work. I will dig in after lunch and try some other ideas.